# Is "cast the balance to some/someone's side" a standard usage or a figure of speech?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, word-usage

> ...this biass, though, perhaps, it may not appear in a few throws, will certainly prevail in a great number, and will cast the balance entirely to that side. (David Hume, [*Of the Rise and Progress of the Arts and Sciences*, I.XIV.3](http://www.econlib.org/library/LFBooks/Hume/hmMPL14.html))

The meaning of this sentence is clear. But is the style of “**Cast the balance to that side**” a very literal one? Can I use it in scholarly writing?

For example,

> China has concentrated government, huge population..., but in her competition with America, she must be the loser, because democracy and freedom will cast the balance entirely to America’s side.

Is “**Cast the balance to some/someone’s side**” a standard usage or a figure of speech?

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty standard though a bit archaic (used in Jeremiah Whitaker Newman's "The Lounger's Common-place Book" published 1838, in the "Commentary Critical and Explanatory on the Whole Bible" by Robert Jamieson, A. R. Fausset and David Brown, published 1871 etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* a figure of speech because it isn't referring to an actual [balance](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Balance_justice.png). However, the expression is absolutely standard. I wouldn't think twice about seeing it in the *New York Times.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it, but "tilting the balance" is used more often.